# Encrypting password using cipher tool fails for data-bridge-config.xml

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 API Manager 220 and following [Encrypting+Passwords+with+Cipher+Tool documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Encrypting+Passwords+with+Cipher+Tool). When encrypting the Xpath value: `//dataBridgeConfiguration/keyStorePassword` cipher-tool.sh runs without prompting any errors. But at the server startup time I am getting below error;

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-08-29 15:34:40,370] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiverServiceComponent} - Error while starting binary data receiver {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiverServiceComponent}
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56)
at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:225)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver.startSecureTransmission(BinaryDataReceiver.java:119)
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiver.start(BinaryDataReceiver.java:75)
at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.binary.internal.BinaryDataReceiverServiceComponent.activate(BinaryDataReceiverServiceComponent.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the error logs BinaryDataReceiverServiceComponent is failing due to incorrect keystore passwords. When encrypting using cipher tool there's a known issue that stresses users to use the alias `DataBridge.Config.keyStorePassword`. Thus, you need to configure your cipher-tool and cipher-text files to use the above alias for the `data-bridge.xml` file(please refer below).

entry for the **cipher-tool.properties**

```
DataBridge.Config.keyStorePassword=repository/conf/data-bridge/data-bridge-config.xml//dataBridgeConfiguration/keyStorePassword,false
```

entry for the **cipher-text.properties**

```
DataBridge.Config.keyStorePassword=[wso2carbon]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Wish if this was properly documented or if wso2 has followed a guideline/fomatting in providing aliases.

Comment: @YasasDeSilva this is a corner case where the user must use `DataBridge.Config.keyStorePassword` for the encryption. You can follow the DOM path format(if it is XML) for other places as specified in the doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Encrypting+Passwords+with+Cipher+Tool